# How do I initialize constructor and state in a Gatsby arrow function component?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have an arrow function component like so:

```
const Slideshow = () => {
  ...
  return(
    ...
  );
}
```

I want to initialize a constructor like how you would in class components:

```
class Slideshow extends React.Component() {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };
    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
  }
  ...
}
```

I'm using Gatsby for my project, and I static query my data in the Slideshow component. I want to conditionally display this data based on the click of a div. How do you initialize a constructor in a arrow function component? What is the best way to approach this?

Solution:
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10523

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to have a constructor in a functional component. The way to do state in a functional component is with the `useState` hook

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Slideshow = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const toggleModal = () => setModal(previousValue => !previousValue);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

There's no need to bind the toggle function to `this`, since there is no `this`. For more information on hooks, see react's documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html